# QUERY Function Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I need to pull data from Cell into another Cell if Cell in A = to Cell in A from another sheet. I added link into google spreadsheet. Let me know if you can help me.https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18qZNx58i2LRIj24S6uog8su5-NbdR2_Rwu9AkPSepzw/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

delete everything in your B column and use in B1:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1:A, 'Data Page'!A:B, 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much fo your help. I want to have better understand so not keep asking stupid questions. Would you mind to explain what does 2,0 mean in your formula?

Comment: @Avetis sure. 2 stands for "return 2nd column". 'Data Page'!A:B has 2 columns eg. 2 stands in this case for B column. 0 means "exact match" eg. "search A column in range datapage!A:B and return 2nd column only in case of an exact match"

Comment: And last question. I just copy pasted into my main sheet. But 1-Formula is filling down all rows bellow even i dont have data in B Cell. And Missing data in the cell where i pasted the formula. https://prnt.sc/20t5p8t and I am taking data from this tab https://prnt.sc/20t6qzu Would you mind take a look again please? Thank you

Comment: @Avetis hard to tell like this but if I would need to guess without you providing a copy of your sheet... delete everything in N2:N range and put this formula only into N2 cell: `=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B, 'Company Rates'!A:B, 2, 0)))`